# How do I turn off the HAL browser on my product?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Testing was easy with the HAL browser in Spring Data Rest, but I would like to turn off the HAL browser in the product version.

I think there are two ways.

1. Separate the controller that applies only to the product version profile to prevent routing.
2. At build time, block dependecy references by profile. (In my case maven, exclude setting)

I do not know if this is a good way. Is there any alternative, or why should not I turn off the HAL browser?

Comment: I didn't get your first point. But the second point looks good approach (to exclude dependency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is by using a maven profile to enable the HAL-browser

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>HAL_BROWSER</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 ....
```

if you want the HAL-browser switched on, just launch your app like:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -PHAL_BROWSER
```

Comment: This is a very useful method for me. thank.
Conversely, when applying a profile, how do I exclude the dependency of the Rest HAL?